# Пустые массивы после работы регулярного выражения

Tags: php

Скажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо поправить в регулярном выражении, чтобы результат выполнения не содержал пустые массивы?

```
$text = 'Our sites: example.com, www.example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com.';
$pattern = '#(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:".,<>?«»“”‘’]))#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

[image]

Пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d36be59ca84cc8c796709331bf73598625b7029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *что необходимо поправить в регулярном выражении, чтобы результат выполнения не содержал пустые массивы?*

Проще написать новый шаблон, чем разобраться в существующем:

```
$text = 'Our sites: example.com, www.example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com.';

$pattern = '~https?://(?:www\.)?\w+(?:\.\w+)+|www\.\w+(?:\.\w+)+~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => www.example.com
            [1] => http://example.com
            [2] => https://example.com
            [3] => http://www.example.com
            [4] => https://www.example.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` выводит вам все совпадения, ВСЕ совпадения с наибольшим "счетом", так сказать, идут в массив с индексом `[0]`, все остальные в остальные)). Просто берите значения по нулевому индексу `$matches[0]`, потому что у вас в остальных будет **мусор** что-то вроде:

```php
[1] => [
    [0] => .com
    [1] => .com
    [2] => .com
]

[2] => [
    [0] => www.
    [1] => 
    [2] => www.
]
```

Можете заменить регулярку на эту:

```php
$pattern = '/((https?:\/\/)?(www.)?)?[\w\d]+.com/m';
```

---

**P.S.:**  Видел вы задавали ранее вопрос на stackoverflow про регулярку. Так вот, человек который ответил на ваш вопрос и дал вам такую регулярку - он... Он видимо побывал в **аду** и написал, что там увидел **:)**

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ.